# Pourquoi « actif » signifie "assets", et « passif » "liabilities" ?

Tags: finance

[Qu'est-ce qui est actif dans les actifs ? Qu'y a-t-il de passif dans les passifs ?](https://www.bitpanda.com/academy/fr/lecons/quest-ce-que-lactif-et-le-passif)

J'établis une analogie entre le français et l'anglais, puisque l'anglais a emprunté "actif" et "passif" au français. En anglais, "active" ne signifie pas "assets" et "passive" ne signifie pas "liabilities", même si ces notions existent en anglais ! Au demeurant, "active" et "passive" ne sont pas des substantifs en anglais.

[image]

[Source de l'image](https://www.coveto.fr/article-inutile-d--etre-un-specialiste-pour-comprendre-son-bilan-comptable-1471-274-1.html).

Comment: Répondre à cette question, du moins telle qu'elle est posée, demande une certaine compréhension des mécanismes financiers, la question ne serait-elle pas mieux sur [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) ?  (Du point de vue grammatical  *active* et *passive* peuvent être des substantifs en anglais).

Comment: Si je lis la page à laquelle tu renvoies "un actif est quelque chose qui a de la valeur que vous possédez", ça correspond bien à la definition de ***assets** → *Any property or object of value that one possesses, usually considered as applicable to the payment of one's debts*.  Idem pour passif  :  "votre passif représente les activités et les entreprises qui vous coûtent de l'argent" → ***liabilities**: An amount of money in a company that is owed to someone and has to be paid in the future, such as tax, debt, interest*.

Comment: La différence semble être une question de point de vue, en français on se place du point de vue bilan comptable, chiffres (actif/passif) et en anglais du point de vue de la personne (elle possède ou elle doit de l'argent).

Comment: @None C'est possiblement le même point de vue, [_assets_](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=asset) venant de _assez_ dans le sens de _sufficient estate_ (pour couvrir les dettes). Ça semble être à cause de Beaumarchais (par ex. [ici](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5452641z/f174.item.r=passif)), mais on avait déjà le syntagme _dette active/passive_ 200 ans avant ([Bodin](https://books.google.com/books?id=J3RMAAAAcAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=J.%20Bodin%2C%20R%C3%A9publique&pg=PP5#v=snippet&q=s%C3%A9nat%20craignoit&f=false)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conformément à cette source officielle [Entreprendre, le site d’information administrative et de démarches pour les entreprises](https://entreprendre.service-public.fr/vosdroits/F31439)

`Assets`

> L'actif comprend tous les biens et droits que possède l'entreprise :
> bâtiments, fonds de commerce, matériel, créances, brevets déposés, par
> exemple.
>
> Il distingue l'actif immobilisé (fonds de commerce, matériel
> notamment) et l'actif circulant (stocks, personnel, créances, solde
> bancaire créditeur, par exemple).
>
> Les éléments de l'actif ont une valeur économique positive (entrée de
> ressources).

`Liabilities`

> Le passif est constitué des capitaux propres : Fonds qui ont été versées par les associés. Ils sont
> composés du capital social (sommes investies au moment de la création
> de l'entreprise par les associés), de la réserve (bénéfices qui n'ont
> pas été distribués) ou du résultat net de l'entreprise (ce que
> l'entreprise a gagné ou perdu pendant un exercice) et des dettes.

Dans le [Dictionnaire universel de commerce datant de 1742](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dettes%20actives%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) - Volume 3 - Page 53, l'auteur définit les "**dettes actives**" (*les sommes dont on est créancier*) et les "**dettes passives**" (*sommes d'argent dont on est débiteur vis à vis de ses créanciers*).

Je pense que les termes "actif" et "passif" en sont dérivés pour apparaître  postérieurement dans le code civil Napoléonien(1803), puis en comptabilité.

**`--Edit--`**
actif et passif, dans le sens *assets and liabilities* n'apparaissent pas dans le [dictionnaire de 1742](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dettes%20actives%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), mais on les y voit en qualité d'adjectifs associés à "dettes".

Dans le [code civil](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Code_Civil_des_Fran%C3%A7ais_Nouvelle_%C3%A9diti/Xk1iAAAAcAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=0) (1803), on les rencontre en tant que noms dans les articles relatifs aux biens et dettes des epoux, notamment "actif/passif de la communauté".

Dans un [manuel comptable de 1842](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Organisation_et_comptabilit%C3%A9_des_fabriq/8fQNAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=0), les termes *actif et passif* sont employés dans leur sens actuel.

Comment: Désolé, je ne bitte rien dans vos deux derniers paragraphes. Premièrement, pourquoi avez-vous effleuré "dettes actives" et "dettes passives" ? Deuxièmement, comment savez-vous que « actif » et « passif » sont dérivés du Code civil napoléonien de 1803 ? Je ne connais rien à la loi française ! SVP modifiez votre réponse pour élaborer?

Comment: @user32570: voir la modification dans ma réponse

Answer (score 1):

Le cnrtl est assez fourni sur le sujet: https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/actif.

On y trouve la définition pour le substantif *actif*, avec une citation du code civil de 1804:

> Tout ce qui, dans un bilan, constitue les biens non grevés de dettes d'une personne ou d'une entreprise
>
> "*Après l'acceptation de la communauté par la femme ou ses héritiers, l'**actif** se partage, et le **passif** est supporté de la manière ci-après déterminée (...)*"

L'usage en tant que substantif dans ce sens est attesté dès 1762:

> par substantivation de I 3, fin. « ensemble des biens possédés », 1762 (Pt Rob.)

Tandis que l'usage financier en tant qu'adjectif remonte lui à **1576** (dette active et dette passive):

> 3. 1576 debtes **actives** « dettes pour lesquelles on est créancier » (J. Bodin, République, VI, 1, ds Hug. : Le Senat craignoit les registres et enseignemens publiques, qui decouvroient les biens d'un chacun et les debtes actives et passives)

De mon point de vue, les termes français ont l'avantage d'être des contraires (actif vs passif), ce qui n'est pas vraiment le cas en anglais ( asset=avoir/bien/atout/richesse vs liability=responsabilité/fardeau/dette).

Answer (score -1):

"Actif" parce que ça sert à produire des choses, "passif" parce que c'est un genre de "dette" - l'un fait tourner la boîte, l'autre la ralentit. "Actif" va dans le sens de l'activité de l'entreprise, alors que le "passif" la freine.

"Liabilities" est proche de "dette", et le passif contient les dettes. "Asset" est un terme positif, de même qu'*actif*. Un "asset", c'est un *atout* pour une compagnie, qui lui permet de produire. Un "asset" va dans le sens de l'activité de l'entreprise, alors qu'une "liability" la freine.